# Custom Query on field area, is not display a option

Tags: azure-devops

I need to create a query where I can found my test point assigned and check the status, but I'm not looking at the test point option on the query area, I need another configuration for can do it this query?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaBxk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKqaa.png)

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve your issue? Can you provide a minimal example of your query?

Comment: I'm tried to get all my test point assigned to my with different status but I'm not able to found the test point like a field

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a query where I can found my test point assigned and
>   check the status.

If I'm not misunderstand, what you want seems be able to see the test point and the state directly from the query result.

If this, just need to go **Column options** , and then add the `State` and `Test point` column.

Then you will see these 2 parts in your query result:

[image]

Comment: I tried and get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKqaa.png

Comment: @lestat_hn, did you configure this field into the process that this project is using? You can go organization setting -> process, to add this filed.